# DJango pick Operating system username instead of user name present in settings file

Tags: python, django

**About the issue**

I created the project using command `django-admin startproject test` and updated the settings file to have mysql database details. Apart from that nothing added/updated/deleted in code.

**Database details in config file**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        "Name": "django",
        "User": "root",
        "Password": "",
        "Host": "localhost",
        "Port": "3306"
    }
}
```

Then ran the command `python manage.py runserver` and gave me very strange error.

It says Access denied for user pankaj@localhost

**Question**

Settings file has username = root, why django pick operating system username

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django settings names must be [all uppercase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/#creating-your-own-settings).

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        "NAME": "django",
        "USER": "root",
        "PASSWORD": "",
        "HOST": "localhost",
        "PORT": "3306"
    }
}
```